# Neither Token name nor supply shown in etherscan, instead shown "() N/A"

Tags: erc-20, dapps, etherscan

Recently, I've created an ERC20 token on Etherscan and verify the source code but my token information such as token name and total supply not showing up..Instead  it shows balance: 0 N/a and supply also 0 N/A.Moreover I've done a first transaction of 15 usd..

I've attached the image below.

[image]

it's been 1 and half hour now..

Comment: Would be helpful if you provide the source code and/or the contract address in plaintext

Comment: sure, the contract page is https://etherscan.io/address/0xbc0a40d1eee51c49bfa4f88a3f28417a53de5044

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues.

1. While *decimals* is not strictly part of the standard most ERC20 tokens have the information. But it should be named `decimals` while you have it as `decimal`. That's probably why Etherscan doesn't find the information.
2. Same goes for your variable `tokenSupply_`. It should be named `tokenSupply`. And the same is true for name and symbol; they should be named `name` and `symbol`.

Comment: ohh!! but it was showing the information in testnet(rinkeby) with the same exact code..How come?

Comment: There is an contract https://etherscan.io/address/0xbb23bd739eb0744d0f9bfe60012dbce0c5eb7593#code, they also defined variable name as tokenname, but they also defined function name to access the name variable. is it fine doing so..

Comment: Maybe you can define those somewhere either when verifying or somewhere in etherscan settings

Comment: Well, I haven't done anything like that..if I change variable name from tokenname, tokensymbol and tokenSuplly_ to name, symbol,totatsupply, do I have to create a function also for returning their values.

Comment: No, public variables get getters generated automatically